# Docker: failed to export image: failed to create image: failed to get layer

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I got the following error:

> failed to export image: failed to create image: failed to get layer
>   sha256:xxxxxxxxxxxxx: layer does not exist

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM openjdk:8
COPY ./lib/ /usr/src/app/BOOT-INF/lib/
COPY ./lib/entities-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/src/app/BOOT-INF/lib/entities-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY ./app/ /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src
CMD ["java", "-cp", "app/", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

**Output**:

```
Step 3/6 : COPY ./lib/entities-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/src/entities-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
 ---> 3acb1f6c911a
Step 4/6 : COPY ./app.jar /usr/src/app.jar
failed to export image: failed to create image: failed to get layer sha256:33a94c44f7804ae3f57b9e72f94323c15cef7267be7eb95d90d2a1673c4b33b9: layer does not exist
```

Second run always helps - error disappears.
I'm building multiple different images (different jars), with different Dockerfiles in different directories. But content of Dockerfiles is the same.

I think this error appeared after I add:

```
COPY ./lib/entities-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/src/app/BOOT-INF/lib/entities-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I don't want to remove that row: app and entities is my libs. If I remove row - I'll got one layer with thirdparty libs (50mb) merged with entities (2mb).

Comment: docker version? If you look at docker bugs in the official repo, it's described there.

Comment: @AlexKarshin
`Docker version 18.05.0-ce, build f150324782`
can you share the link of bug?
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36573 ?

Answer (score 97):

This problem occurs with a specific sequence of `COPY` commands in a multistage build.

More precisely, the bug triggers when there is a `COPY` instruction producing null effect (*for example if the content copied is already present in the destination, with 0 diff*), followed immediately by another `COPY` instruction.

A workaround could be to add `RUN true` between `COPY` statements:

```
COPY ./lib/ /usr/src/app/BOOT-INF/lib/
RUN true
COPY ./lib/entities-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/src/app/BOOT-INF/lib/entities-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
RUN true
COPY ./app/ /usr/src/app/
```

Another way that seems to work is to launch the build using `BUILDKIT`, like that:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --tag app:test .
```

See: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37965

Comment: Can you explain why `RUN true` works? It worked for me apparently.

Comment: The DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 worked. It would be nice, if anyone has explanation on why this worked, and should we be using this flag all the time

Comment: `RUN true` works. See the linked issue in github for additional details.

Comment: What is the RUN true alternative in distroless containers?

Comment: @alex-jesper `RUN [[ $true ]]` maybe

Answer (score -2):

I received this error, but it didn't tell me anything.  If you want it to output the actual error, use this:

```
docker-compose -f "docker-compose.yml" up --remove-orphans --force-recreate' <optional service: e.g. "nginx">
```

From:

> ERROR: Service 'nginx' failed to build: failed to export image: failed to create image: failed to get layer sha256:63d3...: layer does not exist

To:

> Creating project_nginx ... done
>   Attaching to project_nginx
>   nginx_1  | 2019/06/12 03:27:30 [emerg] 1#1: BIO_new_file("/etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)

From there I could track down the actual issue.  But, from the original error, you have no way of knowing what actually caused the failure.