# docker build failure - failed to export image: failed to set parent sha256:xxx: unknown parent image ID

Tags: docker, docker-image, docker-build

```
Step 11/21 : RUN mkdir -p $G_PATH/resource
 ---> Running in 1ff0dcdd372e
Removing intermediate container 1ff0dcdd372e
 ---> 01793ec6b057
Step 12/21 : COPY build/libs/test.jar $G_PATH
failed to export image: failed to set parent sha256:01793ec6b05731eb0c4d61a4f907a3fc073ac7f1e0eb5e22a4855bfdf8eb83d0: unknown parent image ID sha256:01793ec6b05731eb0c4d61a4f907a3fc073ac7f1e0eb5e22a4855bfdf8eb83d0
```

I found unexpected error when I build docker image.
It's not happened every time, but sometimes.
I tried to find solution, but I couldn't find any proper explanation and solution. Especially, I don't think docker version upgrade is the solution. Because, This error has not been happened from other server, which use same docker version. (Let me add version by the way)

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.6
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        481bc77
 Built:             Sat May  4 02:35:57 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.6
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.8
  Git commit:       481bc77
  Built:            Sat May  4 01:59:36 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

docker file:

```
FROM xxxx:latest

ARG VCS_REF
ARG DOCKER_TAG
LABEL xxxx=$VCS_REF

ENV G_PATH=/service
ENV VCS_REF=$VCS_REF
ENV DOCKER_TAG=$DOCKER_TAG

# Make directories
RUN mkdir -p $G_PATH
RUN mkdir -p $G_PATH/config
RUN mkdir -p $G_PATH/runtime
RUN mkdir -p $G_PATH/resource

# Copy jar file to directory
COPY build/libs/test.jar $G_PATH

....
```

Please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: can you post the docker file?

Comment: @Mogi I posted it

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62409523/9279181

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: failed to export image: failed to create image: failed to get layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51115856/docker-failed-to-export-image-failed-to-create-image-failed-to-get-layer)

Comment: whats `xxxx:latest`...?

Comment: @Mogi thst is just base image. It is created by our company and I replaced it to xxxx due to privacy issue.

Comment: maybe thats the problem.. where do you keep all of you packages? docker hub, or some kind of private registry? is there a chance someone is updated the images and it is not synced with the place you are building the new image?
can you try `docker rmi` this image before building so docker will pull it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this issue many times it worked as my solution. Can you try to check the space(check space df -h) on the cluster and clean the space(docker system prune -af) and then pull the image on the cluster.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem : the previous "layer" was deleted before the new one was built.

Because I had a script that cleaned the VM unused volumes every minute:

```
$ crontab -l
* * * * *   /opt/scripts/prune_docker.sh > /var/log/cron/prune_docker.log 

$ cat /opt/scripts/prune_docker.sh
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/docker system prune -a -f

/usr/bin/docker volume prune -f
```

Now I clean the VM only once a week :

```
$ crontab -l
30 23 * * 0     /opt/scripts/prune_docker.sh > /var/log/cron/prune_docker.log
```